# Search Bar is not showing on main page in mobile but works fine the rest of the site

Tags: search, mobile

MOBILE ISSUE The website is [www.Storksplows.com](http://www.Storksplows.com) when clicking the magnifying glass nothing appears on the home page. I feel like something is covering it because the keyboard appears and if you type and press enter it performs the search but without it appearing most people do not know they can actually search. As stated it works fine on the other pages of the site any help would be appreciated. Magento 2.3.4

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input** this error in console log is causing the problem. Try to find this. If you resolve this everything will work fine.

Comment: I did notice the error but I am not skilled in Javascript at all. I have some web design knowledge but do not know the first thing about even finding what is causing the error

Comment: You can try removing each section at a time and see which section causing the error. If you can find the section responsible for it, finding the exact problem will be easy.